# D3 scatter plot - visible points outside the chart after zoom

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I've a question related to adding zoom into a chart.

I built a scatter plot with zoom/pan and everything is working except for the fact that when I use the zoom on the chart, I can see some points outside the chart "area" and I really want to avoid that.

The zoom behavior looks like this:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .x(xScale)
            .y(yScale)
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

And the zoomed function like this:

```
function zoomed() {
    var panX = d3.event.translate[0];
    var panY = d3.event.translate[1];
    var scale = d3.event.scale;

    panX = panX > 10 ? 10 : panX;
    var maxX = -(scale-1)*width-10;
    panX = panX < maxX ? maxX : panX;

    panY = panY > 10 ? 10 : panY;
    var maxY = -(scale-1)*height-10;
    panY = panY < maxY ? maxY : panY;

    zoom.translate([panX, panY]);


    main.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    main.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    main.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return xScale(d[0]); } )
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d[1]); } )
        .attr("r", 5);
}
```

You can see a working example (and all the code) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/klingex/y6ssvm0v/)

Is there a way I can define the "area" of scope for the zoom, so any point outside this area is not visible? or can I add something into the zoomed function to fix this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to restrict the `g` region of the element in which your points are drawn using a clip path

See http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/duwyay3y/1/ for the code.

First define your clip path:

```
var clip = main.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("id", "clip-rect")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
```

then add to the `g` element

```
main.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .selectAll("circle")
    ...
```